# Arabic language not supported

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have an issue.

I am working on dual language i.e arabic and english language in my project.

Everything working fine but when i try to show validation in arabic it doesnot support instead shows ???? for arabic text.

What i did was in lang folder i created ar folder where validation text for arabic are written in validation.php file as

```
 <?php
 return [
  'required'             => 'ال :attribute مطلوب',

   'attributes' => [
    'first_name'=>'مطلوب'
   ],

];
```

i have included utf-8 in html too.

What else i need to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do i have to change setting in phpstorm for supporting unicode utf-8. I think every editor works for utf-8 .Even though i needto change wherei can find setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you added in your HTML header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

if the above is true

try to put this

```
\Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');
```

in your **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** file, **boot** method

Comment: you mean like this  public function boot()
    {
      \Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');
    }

Comment: yep that what i mean

Comment: in app.php i have included 'locale' => 'ar', but still no lucks

Comment: Arabic not working only with validation or in whole application ?

Comment: Only for validation, forms and other stuffs are working fine @Muhammed

Comment: try to open file with notepad++   , On the top menu is "Encoding" - set this to "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" and then save the file

Comment: what about phpstorm i donot have notepad ++ i am using phpstorm .Dont every editor support unicode utf-8???

Comment: Yea it's support but to can make sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121021/discussion-between-anand-shrestha-and-muhammed).